# How to check if all the input values are equal to my data?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach

I have 32 items in my array, all of them have these properties: id, word, image. User has to guess what's in all the images and write their guess in inputs (so 32 inputs in total). I need to check if the input equals my arrays property "word" and then when clicked a button (type submit, all my pic's and inputs are in a form) display some text for example **"Oops! Guess again"** if wrong and **"Yay! You got it correctly"** if right. The text should appear below every input. I displayed all the pictures and inputs with a forEach, and i'm using bulma framework for this page:

```
const wordBox = info.forEach((words) => {
  mainColumns.innerHTML += `
  <div class="column is-one-quarter">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-4by3">
      <img src=${words.image} alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-content">
        <input class="input" id="text" type="text" placeholder="Įvesk žodį">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>`;
});
```

Any ideas?
This is how it should look like (the result should appear in content place)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

I use change instead of a button click

```js
const info = [
{word:"flower",image:"flower.gif"},
{word:"boat",image:"boat.gif"}
];

const mainColumns = document.getElementById("mainColumns");
mainColumns.innerHTML = info.map(({image,word}) => 
`<div class="column is-one-quarter">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-4by3">
      <img src=${image} alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-content">
        <input class="input" data-word="${word}" type="text" placeholder="Įvesk žodį">
        <span class="correct hide">Yay</span>
        <span class="wrong hide">NOO</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>`).join("");
mainColumns.addEventListener("change",function(e) {
   const correct = [...mainColumns.querySelectorAll("[data-word]")].map(input => {
     if (input.value) {
       const correct = input.value === input.dataset.word;
       parent = input.closest("div");
       parent.querySelector(".correct").classList.toggle("hide",!correct)
       parent.querySelector(".wrong").classList.toggle("hide",correct);
       return correct ? 1 : 0;
     }
     else return 0;
     }).reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
   document.getElementById("correct").innerText = correct;
})
```

```css
#mainColumns { display:flex; }
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="mainColumns"></div>
Correct: <span id="correct"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to filter the word array with word from the input value. Then  check if the length is equal zero, No match, if the length is greater than one, then there is a match.

```
const status = wordBox.filter(item => item.word === inputWord)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd move towards keeping the objects and the HTML separate, binding the HTML to the object and vice versa. This means including a couple more properties to your array elements.

```js
let info = [{
  image: 'flower.png',
  word: 'flower',
  content: '',
  guess: ''
}];

function bindWords() {
  info.forEach((words) => {
    mainColumns.innerHTML = `
  <div class="column is-one-quarter">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-4by3">
      <img src=${words.image} alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-content">
        <input class="input" data-word="${words.word}" type="text" placeholder="Įvesk žodį" value="${words.guess}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      ${words.content}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>`;
  });
}

bindWords();
check.addEventListener('click', () => {
  info = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card')).map(el => ({
    image: el.querySelector('img').src,
    word: el.querySelector('.input').dataset.word,
    guess: el.querySelector('.input').value,
    content: el.querySelector('.input').value === el.querySelector('.input').dataset.word ? 
      'Correct' : 'Incorrect'
  }));
  bindWords();
});
```

```html
<div id="mainColumns"></div>
<button id="check">Check Answers</button>
```